# sonar-maven-plugin 5.1.1 not found

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I've just installed the latest version of SonarQube (5.1.1) and when I try to run the sonar:sonar target, I get an error:

```
Embedded error: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin': POM 'org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:5.1.1
```

I've checked here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar/sonar-maven-plugin

And it seems that version 5.1.1 of the sonar-maven-plugin has not been pushed to the public repo(s).

Is that so or am I looking in the wrong location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sonar-maven-plugin is an independent project that does not follow SonarQube versioning. 
Correct command-line is `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar`

The groupId mvn.codehaus.sonar is for internal use.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that `mvn sonar:sonar` shouldn't be used at all?

Comment: `mvn sonar:sonar` is the shortcut of `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin::sonar`, so yes it must be used !
Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. When I ran `mvn sonar:sonar` it automatically tried to use version 5.1.1 of the sonar-maven-plugin. If sonar-maven-plugin is an independent project that does not follow SonarQube versioning, why does it default to the same version as the SonarQube server? Unless I'm misunderstanding something here, `mvn sonar:sonar` cannot be used, but you have to explicitly specify the version somewhere.

Comment: Forget `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin`. It is no more used. It is deployed only for displaying a clean error message in old environments (that I don't describe here). To sum-up, it's simple. Only `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin::sonar` must be used, **whatever the SonarQube version**. If you want to fix the version in your pom or somewhere else, then the version is 2.6 at that time.

Comment: I think my answer still deserves to be marked as accepted. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: the name obviously has been changed to `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin` with current version 3.2. Is that right? @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource

Comment: @vvursT `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin` is still supported. It relocates to `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin` under the hood. Both can be used. The advantage of the first one is that it benefits from the alias `sonar:sonar`.