# SonarQube 5.1.2 and maven 3.3 integration

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I am trying to integrate `SonarQube 5.1.2` with `Maven 3.3`. But I think it's only supported till `SonarQube` version `5.1`.

When I run `mvn sonar:Sonar`

> Embedded error: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.codehaus.sonar:Sonar-mav
>   en-plugin': POM 'org.codehaus.sonar:Sonar-maven-plugin' not found in repository:
>    Unable to download the artifact from any repository
>
> org.codehaus.sonar:Sonar-maven-plugin:Pom:5.1.2
>
> from the specified remote repositories:
>     central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sonar-maven-plugin 5.1.1 not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797839/sonar-maven-plugin-5-1-1-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The correct command-line is mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar (see the difference of groupId). It is supported by all versions of Maven 3 and SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I am getting this error after running your command:
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependenci
es could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mo
jo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:son
ar-maven-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.securi
ty.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certifica
tion path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Comment: the goal is missing in your command-line. As a reminder maven command-line is "mvn {groupId}:{artifactId}:{version}:{goal}", so "mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar".

Comment: Thanks Simon. We may have some network issue here. It works outside of the network.

Answer (score 0):

`sonar:Sonar` != `sonar:sonar` beware of the spelling.

Comment: Thanks Kraal. but sonar:sonar didn't make any difference